Why is Row Percentage Still Showing in Flextable?
Despite using (what I believe to be) sufficient code to remove all percentages, they are still showing up in my flextable. If only attaining frequency for 1 variable, does the package simply require percentage to be shown?
d <- as_flextable(table(iris$Species),
                  include.row_percent = FALSE,
                  include.column_percent = FALSE,
                  include.table_percent = FALSE) %>%
  hline_top(part="all",border=fp_border(width=1.5)) %>% hline_bottom(part="all",border=fp_border(width=1.5))
print(d)


One way to avoid
library(flextable)
table(iris$Species) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  flextable()


